# iphone codes from website

Tags: iphone, frameworks

can anyone tell-->
why the sample codes downloaded from internet when run in xcode
shows the unavailable in project(showing in red color)

and when trying to add manually it not showing the frameworks in
 existing framework list.

thats why i have to create other project and add the contents of 
the downloaded code to my project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust them to your environment and ide. That means: read what xcode says when you try to compile. Usually it is the developer ID, the Base DSK, the Target SDK and the target that don't match.

Comment: You are welcome :) (Please check the answer as answered, so it will show up proper in case someone has the same question)